# Excel calculation just on Active Workbook, looking for a workaround

Tags: excel, vsto, vba

When you have more than one Excel file open, and your VBA/VSTO code calls the `Calculate` function, or turns on Automatic Calculation, Excel will painfully recalculate **all open Workbooks**, not just the active Workbook.

[image]
This is a well-known and well-reported problem, which has been around for years, but Microsoft doesn't seem interested in fixing it.

[Calculate only the active workbook before saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192938/calculate-only-the-active-workbook-before-saving)

[Microsoft Excel wishlist: Workbook level calculation](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10601079-workbook-level-calculation)

Ridiculously, in both VBA and VSTO, Microsoft gives us the ability to:

- recalculate a particular Worksheeet
- recalculate **all** open Workbooks

...but there's no option to just recalculate one particular Workbook.

In the financial company I work for, this is a huge issue.  Our actuaries have big, bulky Excel files, full of formulae, and when they click on Calculate on one Workbook or we perform a calculate before saving a file, they then have to wait several minutes for all other open Excel files to *also* get calculated.

There are two ways around this.

You could run some VBA like this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual 
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
    sh.Calculate 
Next sh
```

..but this isn't guaranteed to work.  Your "Sheet1" might contain formulae pointing to cells in "Sheet2", but other cells in "Sheet2" might have dependencies back on "Sheet1".  So, calculating each Worksheet *once* might not be enough to perform a full calculation on your Workbook.

Alternatively, you could open each Excel file in a separate instance (by holding down ALT as you open the Excel icon).  But then, you lose the full Excel cut'n'pasting functionality, as described here:

[Can't fully cut'n'paste between Excel instances](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/917637/you-cannot-paste-any-attributes-into-a-workbook-in-another-instance-of-excel)

So, my question is... has anyone **found a workaround** for this issue ?

I *just* want to recalculate the cells in the **Active** Excel Workbook.

I wondered if I could add some VBA or VSTO which sets all non-Active Workbooks to "read-only" before I kick off a Calculation on the Active Workbook, thus preventing other Workbooks from being able to be recalculated.  But this isn't possible.  The "`Workbook.ReadOnly`" can only be read, not programmatically set.

Or perhaps adding a handler to the `Worksheet_Calculate` event, which checks if that VBA code which is being run belongs to the Active Workbook, and if not, it aborts attempting to calculate...?  But this event actually gets kicked off **after** that Worksheet has been calculated, so it's too late.

Our company can't be the only one suffering from this issue...

Any advice (other than upgrading to Lotus 1-2-3) ?

Comment: Given that you can [trace a cells' dependends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197707.aspx) in VBA, my first thought is you could do a sort of tree search for dependent cells, calculate the last branches first and work backwards... which would fix the issue you mentioned using `sh.Calculate`. You would pair it with a [`rng.Calculate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834613.aspx) call. Might take some real thinking to write an elegant function for this!

Comment: Thanks Wolfie..  And yes, we did think about this..  but it'd be a nightmare piece of code to write, which is why I thought it'd be safer to somehow "disable" all other open Workbooks during a calculation.  Problem is, when you re-enable calculations on them, it'll kick off a calculation anyway, so we're back where we started !!

Comment: You can open the workbooks using VBA as read only ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx )

Comment: @Luuklag Opening them as read-only would require closing them first, not really ideal (I assume) for the OP!

Comment: @MikeGledhill Yeah as I was writing the suggestion I realised it would probably be tricky to make robust and quick (which is the whole point!), I assume Excel's calculate function does something similar but highly optimised. I'll have a think on this, I've felt this pain too.

Comment: I was looking into this a bit more. And indeed opening them as read only requires them to be closed to begin with. Might not be the best solution. I found this interesting article from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx which hints me to a few options: Using the range.dirty method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/office/ff838797.aspx) or the Workbooks(reference).ForceFullCalculation. The last is really helpfull when building the dependency tree (opening the workbook) takes a long time.

Comment: Probably not the most efficient method, but you could calculate each worksheet in the workbook and then do it again.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses another instance of Excel to avoid multiple workbook calculations. A few lines of the code for using a new instance were taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556292/application-calculation-depending-on-workbook), which deals with a similar topic and may be of interest to you.

You will have to test this for speed in your specific case, since the closing/opening time might not out-weigh the avoided calculations!

**Macro steps**

- Set calculation to manual
- Save and exit the desired workbook
- Open it in a new instance of Excel
- Recalculate
- Save, close and re-open in original instance of Excel.

**Key point** for running this script:

- The macro cannot live within the workbook to be recalculated, since it gets closed (twice) during the process. It should be placed in some other "utility" workbook.

**Code** - see comments for details

```
Sub CalculateWorkbook(WB As Workbook)
    ' Store path of given workbook for opening and closing
    Dim filepath As String
    filepath = WB.FullName
    ' Turn off calculation before saving
    Dim currentCalcBeforeSave As Boolean
    currentCalcBeforeSave = Application.CalculateBeforeSave
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
    ' Store current calculation mode / screen update and then set it to manual
    Dim currentCalcMode As Integer, currentScreenUpdate As Integer
    currentCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    currentScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Close and save the given workbook
    WB.Close savechanges:=True
    ' Open a new INSTANCE of Excel - meaning seperate calculation calls
    Dim newExcel As Excel.Application
    Set newExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ' Could make it visible so that any problems don't leave it hidden in the background
    ' newExcel.Visible = False
    ' Set the calculation mode to manual in the new instance sothat the workbook isn't calculated on opening.
    ' This can't be done without an existing workbook object.
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Set tempWB = newExcel.Workbooks.Add
    newExcel.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    newExcel.CalculateBeforeSave = False
    ' Open the workbook in the new instance of Excel
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Set newWB = newExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    ' Calculate workbook once
    newExcel.Calculate
    ' Close and save the workbook, tempworkbook and quit new instance
    newWB.Close savechanges:=True
    tempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    newExcel.Quit
    ' Re-open in the active instance of Excel
    Application.Workbooks.Open filepath
    ' Reset the application parameters
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = currentCalcBeforeSave
    Application.ScreenUpdating = currentScreenUpdate
    Application.Calculation = currentCalcMode
End Sub
```

Call the above sub by passing it the workbook object you wish to recalculate (this could be done from a button etc).

This has been tested on a *very* simple example workbook, and the concept works. However, please test on a copy of your workbook first, since it has not been fully robustness tested, and has no error handling.

Comment: Thanks for this idea.  Unfortunately, on our network, saving the Excel file, then reloading it...  it's not an option.  It would make the overall save/calculation time even longer.  Thanks for the feedback though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mike, ah no worries, knew it had its drawbacks, if only there was something Excel did *quickly* which could be capitalised on heh! I'll leave this answer here in case it's of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

The method I use for this in my FastExcel product involves setting WorkSheet.EnableCalculation to false for all the worksheets in all non-activeworkbooks and to True for all the worksheets in the active workbook.

This works but has the disadvantage of making the next calculation a Full calculation of the new active workbook when you change the active workbook: so its a tradeoff.

You can try this out in your situation by downloading the trial version of FastExcel from [Download](http://www.decisionmodels.com/Downloads/InstallFxlV3.zip) the 15-day full-featured trial of FastExcel V3 build 231.655.789.380

Then use FastExcel Calculation Options and check the Active Workbook checkbox in the Current Calculation Mode settings;

Disclaimer: I own, develop and market the FastExcel product. The FastExcel component that contains the Active Workbook Calculation code is FastExcel V3 Calc

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Yes, my team and I were discussing this "set the EnableCalculation" flag idea earlier but we decided against it, as once our ActiveWorkbook had finished doing its calculations, we would need to set EnableCalculation back to true... so we're back to the original problem: Excel painfully recalculating the other Workbooks.  So, this wouldn't actually help.

Comment: But you don't need to set enablecalculation back to true for the other workbooks. You only need to change it using an application event when a different workbook becomes active (set old active enablecalculation to false and new active enablecalculation to true). Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: The difficulty is @Charles, that "When you change the value from False to True, Excel recalculates the worksheet" (from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841201.aspx)), so if you enabled it when you switched workbooks, the calculation would happen even if the user didn't want it to?

Comment: As usual the docs are at best misleading. What actually happens is that switching from False to True dirties all the formulas on that worksheet but does not trigger a calculation event in Manual calc mode. In Auto calc mode a calc event happens because some formulas have been dirtied. (BTW In FastExcel you can also have different calculation modes for different open workbooks, so you might have a fast book in Auto and a slow one in Manual). The speed tradeoff of the Active Book calc technique is that the first recalc of the workbook that has just been activated is a Full Calculation

Comment: @Wolfie - See my website http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm for a more detailed explanation of Worksheet.Enablecalculation

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't know that. I guess the OP will have to decide if the full calculation is an acceptable tradeoff, since it could be very costly with lots of tables!

Comment: Yes Data tables can be slow - see https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/excel-what-if-data-tables-faster-calculation-with-vba/ for a suggestion of a possible speedup method

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of large workbooks that require I set calculation mode to manual to prevent constant and unnecessary recalculations. As was pointed out above, Excel allows recalculating the active sheet and ALL open workbooks. I found a workaround that appears to calculate only the active workbook:

```
If Not ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then
    Popup_Msg "Calculating the Workbook"
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
End If
```

(Popup_Msg is a subroutine to display a message in the status bar.)

The workbook is recalculated when required, but other open workbooks are not.

Note: this technique works because calculations were set to Manual upon opening it.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using here?